# Spaces are disappearing after I key in word in my edittext

Tags: java, android, android-layout, filter, simpleadapter

My problem is, I want to search "curry house", let say I insert "curry house". The space will disappear the result. but if I search the result which is without space it work perfectly.

**MainActivity.java**

```
ADAhere = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data, R.layout.mainproductitem, new String[]{"CategoryName"}, new int[]{R.id.mainproductitem});
mainlistproduct.setAdapter(new PrimaryFragment().ADAhere);


        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            mainlistproduct.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            mainlistproduct.setFilterText(cs.toString().trim());

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arg0.length()==0){
                mainlistproduct.clearTextFilter();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`mainlistproduct.setFilterText(cs.toString().trim());`

Every time you type something you automatically trim spaces at the beginning and end.

So..

`curr` -> `curr`
`curry` -> `curry`
`curry[space]` -> `curry[no_space]`
`curry h` -> `curryh`

Comment: erm... one question, if my data is call from from database to listview, and the curry house which content the space is stored in database ad, how can my code to appear search function in listview?

Answer (score 0):

Trim the search string,then replace the space from the string,then search the string.

```
 @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)     {
            // When user changed the Text
          String  input = cs.toString().trim();
          input = input.replace(" ", "");
          mainlistproduct.setFilterText(input);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove trim() from `onTextChanged()`. Just use  `mainlistproduct.setFilterText(cs.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code, try this

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            mainlistproduct.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            mainlistproduct.setFilterText(cs.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arg0.length()==0){
                mainlistproduct.clearTextFilter();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: no error in my code, but it still the same i cant get the result with the space

Comment: Can you please give the code that you set text in your text view

Comment: your email address is?

Comment: actually my listview data is call from database, so if my data that content space ,  there will have problem

Comment: No. I want to see the code where you assign the text in to the text view

Comment: ADAhere = new ListProduct(getActivity(), wordList, R.layout.listproduct,
                                new String[]{"ProductName", "ProductPrice"},
                                new int[]{R.id.listitem, R.id.listitem1});